# How to terminate Colab session programmatically?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

To save consumed compute units in Colab (as there's an option) to pay as you go, how to terminate / shut down Colab session using a code programmatically?

Answer (score 7):

Use the following function

```
from google.colab import runtime
runtime.unassign()
```

It will delete the currently connected runtime and disconnect the notebook.
It's announced [here](https://twitter.com/GoogleColab/status/1569389018311426051).

Comment: It works out well until now Apr 2023.